# how to remove checkout from paypal standard in magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, paypal, magento-1.9, payment-method

I have configured paypal standared with my website, but which is acting as express checkout. I don't need any paypal checkout in the website. How can I change it as a usual payment methods (like payumoney, cc avenue).

Also need to list paypal also in payment method list. Currently it displaying as seperate checkout methods.

How it possible with my magento 1.9 version website?

Comment: Hi Midhun, with Magento 1.9 PayPal Standard Loads Express Checkout - SAME | What you want to do is disable PayPal standard, enable PayPal Express Checkout, put in your credentials and go into the advanced settings and UNCHECK show on 'shopping cart page'. This will remove from the CART page and only show in the LIST on the checkout page; very end before submitting order.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to system -> configuration -> Payment Methods.
2. Click configure button of PayPal Express Checkout.
3. Under Required PayPal Settings, there is a section called Express Checkout - expand that and you'll see the "Enable this solution" setting that you can switch to "No" to disable it.

Comment: No, I mean how to make the paypal checkout as paypal standared, currently in magento 1.9 paypal is coming with paypal express checkout, is there any way to disable this functionality.

Comment: Standard and Express Checkout are essentially the same thing with that version